# No Halves Hath the Heptagram

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, anagram

Here is the heptagram:

[image: heptagram]

Rules are the same as for the [octagram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85499/step-into-the-octagram).  However, the heptagram has the very nice property that all words are unique.  I.e., as you go around, you will not encounter any duplicate words, neither at the vertexes nor along the arrows.

Note to @Randal'Thor and @Sconibulus — You guys correctly observed that the octagram naturally splits into two distinct puzzles, each of which can be considered and solved separately.  However, the heptagram has no such property.  You must follow the solving path continuously through all seven vertexes.  I don't believe it makes the solving process any more or less difficult, it's just a matter of working through one 14-path instead of two 8-paths.

Note to @TwoBitOperation and @BmyGuest — You guys wanted another one.  Here it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer

> INTERACTIONS

Diagram

> [image]